# Is "applying a voltage" the same as "applying a potential" to an electrode?

Tags: electricity, terminology, potential, voltage

From what I understand, voltage is the potential difference, but it seems like the terms are used interchangeably. This is confusing me because I am only just learning what these terms mean. I'm also not sure how either is "applied" - I think applying a voltage to an electrode would mean providing a difference in charge somewhere to allow a current to flow from one to the other, and applying a potential would mean providing it potential energy, which would be done the same way as when applying a voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. [Voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage) is an electric potential difference. The concept of potentials is more general (e.g. gravitational potential) in physics.